# Is the space of continuous functions from a compact metric space into a Polish space Polish?

Tags: pr.probability, gn.general-topology, reference-request

Let $K$ be a compact metric space, and $(E,d_E)$ a complete separable metric space.
Define $C:=C(K,E)$ to be the continuous functions from $K$ to $E$ equipped with
the metric $d(f,g)=\sup_{k\in K}\ d_E (f(k),g(k))$. Is the space $C$ separable?

The result is true when $E$ is the real line; this is Corollary 11.2.5 in Dudley's 
book *Real Analysis and Probability*.

The result is also true when $K=[0,1]$ (if I'm not being too careless) by 
considering $C$ as a subspace of the Skorohod space $D_E[0,1]$, which is 
complete and separable by Theorem 5.6 in Ethier and Kurtz's book *Markov Processes:
 Characterization and Convergence*.

For general $K$, it is not so obvious how to find an explicit countable
dense set in $C$, but I suspect one could modify  Ethier and Kurtz's approach and get a proof.

But surely this result is known, and stated in some book? I've searched through
my library without success.

---

**Update:**  This result is also **Theorem 2.4.3**  of S. M. Srivastava's book *A Course on Borel Sets*. His proof is the same as Kechris's. I have also found an alternative, but false, published proof using the "fact" that $C(K,E)$ is $\sigma$-compact. Beware!

Comment: Which book contains the false "proof"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it appears e.g. as Theorem 4.19 in Chapter I of Kechris' *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*.  (The relevant page is visible in Google Books if it's not in your library.)

Answer (score 1):

We have the following. Fix $X, (Y,d)$ polish spaces where $d$ is some bounded metric. Topologise $C^{0}(X,Y)$ by the metric $d(f,g)=sup_{x\in X}d(f(x),g(x))$. Then one can tweak Kechris' proof to show, that the subspace $S$ of uniformly continuous maps with bounded images, is Polish.

Is it possible to show that $C^{0}(X,Y)$ can be generated by $S$, using point-wise limits of $\omega$-sequences of functions? This would be a useful result.

Comment: This is false: take $X=\mathbb N$ with the discrete distance, and $Y=\{0,1\}$ with its usual distance. Clearly both satisfy your assumptions, yet the set you denote by $C^0(X,Y)$ is not separable: pick two different subsets $A,B$ of $\N$, and consider the distance between their characteristic functions...